# network manager does not work anymore after upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: network-manager

After the upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04, the network manager icon no longer works. When I click on it everything except for VPN connections is greyed out. I got the network up and running configuring netplan directly but it was nice to have the ability to use the icon, quicker and more flexible.

I reinstalled network manager but to no avail, same problem. I cannot get it to work. Has this been replaced in the new version and if yes, is there something I can install to replace it other than always having to go into netplan to reconfigure my network card.

**This is a desktop installation. Please note, I had to change the YAML configuration for renderer from network manager to networkd to get it to work.

## Output of yaml file

> ```
> network:
>   renderer: NetworkManager
> *# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
> *# For more information, see netplan(5).
> network:
>   version: 2
>   renderer: NetworkManager
> *# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
> network:
>   version: 2
>   renderer: networkd
>   ethernets:
>     enp3s0:
>       addresses: 
>         -  192.168.1.10/24
>       gateway4: 192.168.1.254
>       nameservers: 
>         search: [mydomain,otherdomain]
>         addresses: [75.153.176.1, 8.8.8.8]
> ```

## Output of Interfaces

> ```
> (Interfaces)
> *# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
> auto lo
> iface lo inet loopback
> ```

## Output of lshow network

> ```
> *-network                 
>        description: Ethernet interface
>        product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
>        vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
>        physical id: 0
>        bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
>        logical name: enp3s0
>        version: 03
>        serial: 48:5b:39:7c:e2:d3
>        size: 1Gbit/s
>        capacity: 1Gbit/s
>        width: 64 bits
>        clock: 33MHz
>        capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom 
>
> ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd
> > 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
> >            configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=full firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168d-2.fw
> > ip=192.168.1.10 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII
> > speed=1Gbit/s
> >            resources: irq:18 ioport:e800(size=256) memory:fdfff000-fdffffff memory:fdff8000-fdffbfff
> > memory:febf0000-febfffff
> ```

@heynnema - Thanks for your response. I initially tried your suggestions a while back and also after the upgrade, that was the default configuration. Nevertheless, I attempted to do the exact steps you suggested. The results are identical, no LAN connection and greyed out options under the network icon.
In response to question of how many yaml files I may have, please see the following:

## /etc/netplan file listing

ls -l /etc/netplan
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  36 Oct 30 11:11 00-default-nm-renderer.yaml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  36 Oct 27 16:02 00-default-nm-renderer.yaml.old
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 159 Oct 27 15:55 01-netcfg.yaml.old
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 104 Oct 30 10:51 01-network-manager-all.yaml.exp
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 300 Oct 13 21:20 01-network-manager-all.yaml.netd
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 104 Oct 13 23:37 01-network-manager-all.yaml_netman
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 104 Oct 30 11:08 01-network-manager.yaml

## Contents of 01-network-manager.yaml

cat 01-network-manager.yaml
*#Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:

version: 2

renderer: NetworkManager*

Also tried same config in a file named 01-network-manager-all.yam

Same result - no Lan connection and greyed out Ethernet network options under network icon

## uname -r

5.4.0-52-generic

## Revised yaml file (the only file now in netplan)

cat 01-network-manager.yaml

network:
version: 2
renderer: NetworkManager

Same issue, network icon has ethernet network greyed out and LAN not connected. I did remove all files but one however, the system keeps adding in a default yaml file called "00-default-nm-renderer.yaml". When I revert back to networkd control (specified IP address assigned in yaml file) LAN connects with no issues.

## cat 00-default-nm-renderer.yaml

network:
renderer: NetworkManager

/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg does not exist. in fact, there is no etc/cloud directory

## ls -al /etc/netplan

total 24
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct 30 16:21 .
drwxr-xr-x 184 root root 12288 Oct 29 16:05 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    36 Oct 30 15:29 00-default-nm-renderer.yaml
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   300 Oct 30 15:40 01-network-manager.yaml

I just used the default yaml file and it failed the same way, however, it did work at the initial login as my userid login was initializing and then LAN stopped working. I know it worked for a little bit as some apps I start up on initialization that need the LAN connection worked but after initialization completed and I then tried to access the Internet through my browser it failed and I then noticed all my LAN access was no longer working and ip addr didn't see my LAN connection (no IP address)...weird?
Just to be clear though, the icon never ungreyed (if that is a word?)
I don't have a 20.04 CD but I will create one and give your suggestion a try once I get one created.

Booted from a fresh USB version of Ubuntu 20.04. The network icon was quite different and the output was different but it worked.

Comment: Is this a Desktop or Server installation? Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `sudo lshw -C network`.

Comment: When you respond to a request for more info, make sure to let the requester know that you've done so, by starting a new comment with @heynnema (example for me)... that will notify the requester.

Comment: @heynnema - Thanks for trying to assist me. Tried your suggestions and posted my results.

Comment: You didn't follow my instructions. /etc/netplan **still** has multiple .yaml (and other) files. The .yaml that you do show is incorrect, and is **not** a copy of what's in my answer. Please follow my exact instructions. Report back.

Comment: Show me `uname -r`.

Comment: @heynnema Same issue, network icon has ethernet network greyed out and LAN not connected. I did remove all files but the sysrem, however, keeps adding in a default yaml file called "00-default-nm-renderer.yaml". When I revert back to networkd control (specified IP address assigned in yaml file) LAN connects with no issues

Comment: What are the contents of 00-default-nm-renderer.yaml? Tell me if `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg` exists. Show me `ls -al /etc/netplan` again.

Comment: @heynnema  Completed and posted. Thanks again for trying to help me out.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for hanging in there. Delete `/etc/netplan/01-network-manager.yaml`, do `sudo netplan generate` and `sudo netplan apply` and `reboot`. Then recheck your NM GUI again. If the NM GUI doesn't work, then boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and see if NM GUI works there. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema Update posted but I need to still do the second part of your request as indicated in my update. Thanks

Comment: @heynnema Booted from a fresh USB version of Ubuntu 20.04. The network icon was quite different and the output was different but it worked.

Comment: Do backups. Reinstall Ubuntu. Uncheck the "format" box and it should leave your /home alone.

Comment: @heynnema I want ot make sure my other users and myself (on the same computer) do not lose our apps and our data. Would you please clarify a bit more how to do this properly. I do have incremental backups but I prefer not to have to go there.

Comment: You probably should have full backups, or a clone backup. If memory serves me, when you install Ubuntu, it gives an option, if it finds a pre-existing Ubuntu installation, to install over the top of it. If you uncheck the "format" box, it should leave your /home alone. But please do your own homework... ie: don't take my word for it :-)

Comment: @heynnema Yes, I have a problem trying to do your suggested (generally approved) method of reinstalling. Because I have a hardware RAID set, it doesn't seem to recognize that there is an existing installation so it just wants to start from scratch. I guess if I decide to resolve this issue, I will need to do a full backup and reinstall a clean version of 20.04. Dang...Thanks for your assistance, much appreciated.

Comment: @heynnema Had to wipe out the system and reinstall after I did the backups. It was close to an all day thing but all is working as prescribed. Thanks for your assistance

Comment: Thanks for the update. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little unclear from your updates, whether you have ONE /etc/netplan .yaml file, or THREE /etc/netplan .yaml files.

Never mind, delete all of them and replace it with ONE .yaml file, called `01-networkmanager.yaml`, that contains just this:

Note: Make sure to keep the indentation and spacing just as you see it, and no tabs.

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Then:

`sudo netplan generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot`

Then:

Use the NetworkManager GUI settings to configure your wired ethernet connection.

**Update #1:**

We reinstalled Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved:
Had to reinstall 20.04. Now all is working as it should. Sledgehammer instead of an easy fix. Thanks to @heynnema for sticking with me to the end.